# Setting Button Color

Tags: android, button, colors

This works to change colour of button:

```
myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_grey);
```

this doesn't

```
int myColor = R.drawable.button_grey;
myButton.setBackgroundResource(myColor);
```

Doesn't give the button any color. Why, and how to fix?

Comment: What's your log? I have everything working perfectly.

Comment: That's the weird thing. Nothing. The drawable just doesn't render.

Comment: Okay, worked it out (this is probably real dumb, but I'm a novice). I wanted to assign the resource to a variable as I'm extending the `Button` class to add my own methods. I didn't appreciate that if you set the `myColor` as a property of the class, it has to be defined as `static`. Without `static` it doesn't render. Learning all the time!

Comment: Rather than adding the solution to your question and posting an answer that says "This has been solved. See original post.", please post your solution as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("red"));
// or
myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
// or
myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(int,int,int);
```

Comment: Thanks mike, but I want to set the resource not just the color.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a rookie mistake, but it appears that you need to declare the variable that you want to assign your resource to as a `static` variable, i.e., `static int`, if you want to use it as a property of a class (see comments below).

Comment: I went ahead and moved the solution from the question to the answer for you. Please mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will work

```
counter = 1;
        //By Default set color
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (counter == 1)
                {
                   // Default color
                    counter = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    //your color
                    counter = 1;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this lines:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_grey);
myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
int myColor = R.drawable.button_grey;
myButton.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getdrawable(mycolor));
```

Comment: Nope. I've got an error in IDE saying *View cannot be applied to graphics drawable*? :(